# How do I access and use AWS config/credential information in my boto3/python app on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm looking to use information like my mfa_serial provided from the `~/.aws/config` file in my code.

The only way I've been able to figure out how to access it programmatically is by creating something like:

```
import boto3

foo = boto3
mfa_serial = foo.DEFAULT_SESSION._session.full_config['profiles']['default']['mfa_serial']
print(mfa_serial)
```

I feel like there's got to be a better way to access this info, I've read through the documentation and they talk about using environmental variables, but I'm not experienced enough as a programmer to really know intuitively what that means and no one has really explained to me how to use environmental variables in Python. I'm googling it as we speak, but I feel like in terms of AWS I might be missing some trick to it. All the docs just say something like

```
export SOME_ENV_VAR='some value you want'
```

but I have no idea what that means, or where to put it in my code, or if it even goes into my code, or what that line even means.

I've used environmental vars in C# with .NET and ASP.NET, and .NET Core, so I'm somewhat familiar with using a `.env` file, but not sure how it works with Python.

Overall I'm looking to validate MFA. Basically I'm working on building an app that identifies which instances of which services are using which roles, I'm logging in as my AWS user, using the tokens, using boto3 to create an STS client and get_session_token() but I need the mfa_serial, and a way to put in the MFA token, as part of the input for the get_session_token() call

Comment: Excellent question!  I use aws cdk and never worry about ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials . Set up and forget.  aws just reads them for me when the code interacts with aws.  For example, cloudformation.  Actually, a little more complicated as I have mutliple logins.  I use the linux 'export' command to tell aws which profile to use in credentials.  What is your use case for needing programmatic access to config and credentials?

Comment: @jim I'm looking to validate MFA. Basically I'm working on building an app that identifies which instances of which services are using which roles, I'm logging in as my AWS user, using the tokens, using `boto3` to create an STS client and get_session_token() but I need the mfa_serial, and a way to put in the MFA token, as part of the input for the get_session_token() call.

Comment: You should add your comment to your question.  Good explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @jim Thanks! I just added it in. Good suggestion.